# MySQL find/replace with a unique string inside

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

not sure how far I'm going to get with this, but I'm going through a database removing certain bits and pieces in preparation for a conversion to different software.

I'm struggling with the image tags as on the site they currently look like

`[img:<string>]<image url>[/img:<string>]`

those strings are in another field called bbcode_uid

The query I'm running to make the changes so far is

`UPDATE phpbb_posts SET post_text = REPLACE(post_text, '[img:]', '');`

So my actual question, is there any way of pulling in each string from bbcode_uid inside of that SQL query so that I don't have to run the same command 10,000+ times, changing the unique string every time.

Alternatively could I include something inside [img:] to also include the next 8 characters, whatever they may be, as that is the length of the string that is used.

Hoping to save time with this, otherwise I might have to think of another way of doing it.

As requested.

The text I wish to replace would be

`[img:1nynnywx]http://i.imgur.com/Tgfrd3x.jpg[/img:1nynnywx]`

I want to end up with just

`http://i.imgur.com/Tgfrd3x.jpg`

Just removing the code around the URL, however each post_text has a different string which is contained inside bbcode_uid.

Comment: Please edit your question with some real examples of the data and what you want to set `post_text` to.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to do this with `substring_index()`.

The following will work on your example:

```
select substring_index(substring_index(post_text, '[/img:', 1), ']', -1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Method 1

LIB_MYSQLUDF_PREG

If you want more regular expression power in your database, you can consider using LIB_MYSQLUDF_PREG. This is an open source library of MySQL user functions that imports the PCRE library. LIB_MYSQLUDF_PREG is delivered in source code form only. To use it, you'll need to be able to compile it and install it into your MySQL server. Installing this library does not change MySQL's built-in regex support in any way. It merely makes the following additional functions available:

PREG_CAPTURE extracts a regex match from a string. PREG_POSITION returns the position at which a regular expression matches a string. PREG_REPLACE performs a search-and-replace on a string. PREG_RLIKE tests whether a regex matches a string.

All these functions take a regular expression as their first parameter. This regular expression must be formatted like a Perl regular expression operator. E.g. to test if regex matches the subject case insensitively, you'd use the MySQL code PREG_RLIKE('/regex/i', subject). This is similar to PHP's preg functions, which also require the extra // delimiters for regular expressions inside the PHP string

you can refer this link :github.com/hholzgra/mysql-udf-regexp

Method 2

Use php program, fetch records one by one , use php preg_replace
refer : www.php.net/preg_replace

reference:http://www.online-ebooks.info/article/MySql_Regular_Expression_Replace.html